# dataTable custom loading contents

Tags: elasticsearch, datatables

I post a query to elasticsearch with http request via datatable. and get json data as response. I need to bind this data in jquery datatable.

```js
var query="";
    var tableObjects = $("#logTable").DataTable({
        "bProcessing": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost:9200/webproxylog/_search?source=",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "clientname" ,"sortable": false },
            {"mDataProp": "clientip"},
            {"mDataProp": "url"},
            {"mDataProp": "category"},
            {"mDataProp": "respsize","sortable": true},
            {"mDataProp": "loggingdate"},
            {"mDataProp": "reqmethod"},
            {"mDataProp": "resultcode"},
            {"mDataProp": "duration"}
        ],
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
            var sEcho=aoData[0].value
            query = '{"from":"'+aoData[3].value+'","size":"'+aoData[4].value+'","query":{"match_all":{}},"sort": [{"loggingdate": {"order": "desc"}}]}';
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": query,
                "success": function(response){
                    debugger
                    var result_ = new Object();
                    result["sEcho"]=sEcho;
                    result["iTotalRecords"]=response.hits.total
                    result["iTotalDisplayRecords"]=response.hits.total
                    result["aaData"]=response['hits']['hits'].map(functio(i){return i['_source']; })});
                    fnCallback(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error){
                    }
                }});
        },
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": '<select>' +
            '<option value="5">5</option>' +
            '<option value="10">10</option>' +
            '<option value="20">20</option>' +
            '<option value="30">30</option>' +
            '<option value="40">40</option>' +
            '<option value="50">50</option>' +
            '</select> Show'
        },
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function(){
        },
        "aaSorting": [
            [2, 'asc']
        ],
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 15, 20, -1],
            [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    })
```

I wonder if its the way is true for this purpose.? anyway There is an error I couldn't get, in success; response is fine and I prepare result data for fncallback, but problem is when I click next pages shown data in page not changing I checked the query its fine but the problem is datatable inside here..

In normally I use same dt with php datasource everything works fine.. I create custom callback data for dt but something wrong..What should I do?

EDITED: the problem is display size.. but even it looks 5,10 or 50 it always 10 row in page and data not change with pagination

Comment: Is your `aLengthMenu` interfering with your `sLengthMenu`? Remove one, the other or both and see if it works...

Comment: remove `"bServerSide": true,` - when you set this option dataTables expect filtering, paging and sorting to be done serverside. Thats why nothing happens when you click on "next page".